# How to assign NA as the value using mutate() and case_when() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, na, mutate, r-haven

I have a dataframe column consisting of numbers (e.g. with unique values of 1, 2, and 99).

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,1,1,99,2,1,99,1))
```

I want to change all rows where the value is 99 so that the value is NA instead. I tried doing this with `mutate()` and `case_when()`:

```
df <- mutate(df, A = case_when(A==99 ~ NA))
```

...but it converts ***all*** rows to NA (rather than just the rows where the value is 99).

Previous Stackoverflow questions similar to this (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598071/dplyr-case-when-trouble-with-na)) state that using `NA_double_`, `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_` etc fixes this. I tried those but this either:

(a) changes all values in the dummy example I've given here, or
(b) I get an error on my real data (which is a haven_labelled variable):

```
Error in 'mutate()':
In argument: 'A = case_when(...)'.
Caused by error in 'case_when()':
! Failed to evaluate the right-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error:
! object 'NA_double_' not found
```

I know I can set the correct values, and only the correct values, successfully using the method below:

```
df$A[df$A==99] <- NA
```

... but I'd like to understand how to do this using `mutate()` and `case_when()`.

What should I change my code to so that it works using `mutate()` and `case_when()`, whether it's (a) the dummy data presented in this question or (b) the haven_labelled data in my project?

Note: This is ***not*** a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457877/r-replace-specific-value-contents-with-na) because I am asking specifically about using `case_when()` with `mutate()`.

Comment: Use `na_if` rather than `case_when`: `mutate(df, A = na_if(A, 99))`. The `case_when` function needs to return a value for every row. The "correct" version would look like `mutate(df, A = case_when(A==99 ~ NA, TRUE ~ A))` or `mutate(df, A = case_when(A==99 ~ NA, .default= A))`

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick those all worked :) What are the extra parameters (TRUE ~ A and .default=A) doing to make it work?